# Solr returning all the documents on query

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr, solrclient

I have a solr core setup. The schema of the core is as follows:

```
docId: '',
text: ''
```

Here is the screenshot of my core admin page:
[image]

Here is my SolrCrudRepository Interface

```
package com.example.webtool.repository;

import com.example.webtool.model.DocIdModel;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.SolrCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface DocIdRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<DocIdModel, 
String> {
List<DocIdModel> findAllByDocId(String docIds);
List<DocIdModel> getByDocId(String docIds);
}
```

Whenever I am passing a string to any of these two methods, it returns me the entire 14020 docs. But I need only one doc that matches my passed docid.

What is wrong with my code. Any insights??
Please do let me know if any further info is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the `docId` as `72628.txt` but now I am stripping the `.txt` part from the string and I am getting the desired results.